# Magento 2.4 B2B - How to disable buy action and allow quotes?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, b2b

I want to allow B2B quotes in my Magento 2.4 but I want to avoid orders, is it required custom code or I might be able to do it via admin panel only?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need custom code for it, you might be able to disable your checkout via the admin panel in the configuration below.

Disabling checkout

**Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options**

[image: Magento 2 disabling checkout options]

It will make the checkout unaccessible, the call to action to go to the checkout option disappear.

[image: Magento 2 checkout unaccessible]

To enable the B2B capabilities, you might have the Magento B2B module installed then you can enable it, allow quotes and add your customer to a company account.